# Setting the background color of grouped ListView items

Tags: wpf, listview, grouping

I have a `ListView` that contains player data, grouped by team. It looks like this:

```
team 1
  player 1
  player 2
  player 3
  player 4
```

In my case, each team has 3 active players. Therefore I want to show the first 3 players normally, and the remaining players with a different background color.

So the background color does not depend on the item itself, but on its position in the displayed group. Conceptually, I could define the background color depending on a (hypothetical) `CurrentGroup.IndexOfThisItem` property, but I don't know whether such a property exists and how I could access it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Triggers to set the values conditionally

use `DataTrigger` to see if the item meets yout condition and then you can set the desired color via a setter

```
<ListView Name="list">
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                         Value="red">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="red" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}"
                         Value="mygreen">
                <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="green" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for this straight-forward solution, unfortunately it doesn't help me. I clarified my question, since in my case the background color does not depend on the item itself, but on its position in the displayed group.